# unable to open the file in browser using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need assistance from gurus to open the file in browser. I am using following code snippet to get the file from my external CMS and then opening it in browser. But it throws the exception: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\connectToABC\DownloadFileFromABCWEB\System.Byte[]'.`

**Code Snippet**

```
try
{
    var searchParams = new ABCLib.ABCSearchParameters();
    searchParams.WebServiceURL = serverUrl;
    searchParams.MyCredentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxx");

    var contentItems = ABCLib.ABC.SearchABCContent(searchParams);

    if ((contentItems != null) && (contentItems.Length > 0))
    {
        var fileContent = ABCLib.ABCGetFile.GetABCFileContentByName(searchParams.WebServiceURL, searchParams.MyCredentials, "QAABC1000000146789");
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(fileContent.ToString());
        WebClient user = new WebClient();
        Byte[] FileBuffer = user.DownloadData(filePath);

        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        }  
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: `fileContent` contains a byte array not a string, hence you append a byte arrays default `ToString()` text (`"System.Byte[]"`) to your path.

Comment: that is what I was thinking but don't know how to make it working

Comment: Its unclear where the actual path is in your code or what GetABCFileContentByName is or how it works.

Comment: `Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);` instead of `Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);`.  and remove the code lines about `WebClient`, `DownloadData`, and `filePath`.  You already have the file data, no need to try and load it from disk. Also, change `Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());` to use `fileContent.Length`

Comment: @BradleyUffner, it works. Thanks you